# Keyboard dataset with travel distance, operation point, actuation force, and force to bottom out

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a keyboard dataset containing as many following fields as possible:

- keyboard model name
- actuation force
- travel distance
- operation point
- force to bottom out
- shock absorption
- layout (I am mostly interested in qwerty keyboards)
- travel vs force plot

Answer (score 1):

So far I have found these resources:

- This [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/wiki/ripometer#wiki_scissor_switches) thread contains a pretty large number of keyboards and switches along with their peak and activation forces. It can be quite easily parsed.
- [deskthority - Realforce model reference](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Topre_Realforce#Realforce_model_reference)
- [deskthority - Alps SKCL/SKCM series switches](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Alps_SKCL/SKCM_series#Variants)
- [Mechanical Keyboard Switches](https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/mechanical_switches.php) in the catalog of Mechanical Keyboards.